# Search a string that contains special character in MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have problem searching for a long string that contains special character in MS Access. Here is my sample data.

```
staff_Id | hashValue
   1     | 4ENOA2838F09dbfTKXeAdEIKRM91MdsDg0W4pRNChdkGa7iwoVifWH9avZdjrPp1QqLJ0ecNe/X716HlwqfSYA==
```

Here is my SQL command.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE hashValue='4ENOA2838F09dbfTKXeAdEIKRM91MdsDg0W4pRNChdkGa7iwoVifWH9avZdjrPp1QqLJ0ecNe/X716HlwqfSYA==';
```

I had tried googling for escape characters, however I cannot get this working. Hope that you can help me. Thank you.

P.S. I am developing a C# program that interacts with MS-access

**UPDATE**

Here is my SQL query in my C# program that execute the search query.

```
string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE hashValue = @hashedValue";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hashedValue", hashedValue);

        ds = new DataSet(); //have been declared
        dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(); //have been declared
        dbAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        dbAdapter.Fill(ds, "table"); //empty dataset here
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the error message? (if any)

Comment: No error message is being displayed but it will return a empty table after this query is being executed.

Comment: where is the variable `hashedValue` declared?

Comment: yup it is being declared. BTW the code snippet it is a function and hashedValue is part of the arguments

Comment: ok - that makes sence :) but where does it originate from? some code must call the function - where does that code get the string from?

Comment: It got it from other class. I have created breakpoint other classes that placed the string and this function. It seems that the `hashedValue` is being sent successfully.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24322/discussion-between-dale-and-jens-kloster)

Comment: ok - but your still not getting anything back from Access ? perhaps the hashValue it self is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in C# try writing the command like this:

```
string hashValue = @"4ENOA2838F09dbfTKXeAdEIKRM91MdsDg0W4pRNChdkGa7iwoVifWH9avZdjrPp1QqLJ0ecNe/X716HlwqfSYA==";

string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM table WHERE hashValue = '{0}'", hashValue);
```

notis the @ mark before the string. this allows you to have string that look like this:

```
string test = @" \ ";
Console.WriteLine(test); //output: \
```

In your case you can do it like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hashedValue", @hashedValue);
```

but the @-trick works best if its set when the string is declared.

Comment: Hi Jens, Is it possible to add '@' in parameterized query in C#? If it is possible is it okay if you were to show me the code? thanks

Comment: ok - please show your code (C#) that fires the query :), I will update the answer then.

Comment: Hey Jens, it works now :) I didn't noticed your updated post +1

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a query using wildcard?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE hashValue Like "*4ENOA2838F09dbfTKXeAdEIKRM91MdsDg0W4pRNChdkGa7iwoVifWH9avZdjrPp1QqLJ0ecNe/X716HlwqfSYA==*";
```